# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla de distribución de frecuencias por intervalos en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla (resumida) sobre la edad y la cantidad de personas que tienen dicha edad:

| Edad | Frecuencia(Población) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 102332 |
| 1 | 178322 |
| 2 | 168783 |
| 3 | 145687 |
| 4 | 199876 |
| 5 | 156792 |
| ... | ... |
| 100 | 766 |

Mi duda es sobre cómo realizar la tabla de frecuencias por intervalos de edad

| Intervalo | Frecuencia |
| --- | --- |
| 0-10 | x |
| 11-20 | x |
| 21-30 | x |
| 31-40 | x |
| ... | x |
| 91-100 | x |

He intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
censo <- read.delim("censo_datos.txt")

intervalos <- seq(from=0, to=100, by=10)

frecuencias <- cut(censo$Poblacion,
                   breaks = intervalos,
                   dig.lab = 4,
                   right = FALSE)

tabla.frec <- table(frecuencias)

kable(tabla.frec)
```

Pero no resulta. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que ya partes de una tabla de frecuencia, simplemente necesitas agrupar esta por rangos:

```
censo$intervalo <- cut(censo$Edad, intervalos)
aggregate(Poblacion ~ intervalo, censo, sum)
```

Creamos una nueva variable `intervalo` con el que le corresponde a cada edad, luego simplemente con `aggregate()` sumamos por este intervalo.